# Powershell -- get list of all excel files that contain external links to other files

Tags: excel, powershell, datasource

We are migrating our file server to a new file server.  Our Business office has a convoluted mess of folders and subfolders containing over 10,000 excel workbooks.  They know that many of these workbooks contain data source links to other workbooks -- they just don't know which ones.  I'm looking for a PowerShell way to identify and list:

1. Filename/location of any excel file that has external data source links
2. Link(s) contained in each excel file

This must be a common need, but I can't seem to locate any relevant information on how to accomplish this task.

Comment: I'd choose it in EXCEL VBA instead.  You can do wildcarded directory reads, for *.xls?, open each one and scan the formulas in all the sheets, then log the ones you find in the excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the same.. Here is the script that I used.. It`s a powershell script to recursively go through the folder`s structure, open each XLS file and look for external links

LinkSources has a parameter "1" which means link to another excel worksheet as per documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xllink

```
 $path = “path to your data”
$excelSheets = Get-Childitem -Path $path -Include *.xls,*.xlsx -Recurse
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$excel.visible = $false

foreach($excelSheet in $excelSheets)
{
 $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelSheet)
 write-host $excelSheet

 foreach ($link in $workbook.LinkSources(1)){
   write-host "-" $link; 
 }
 $workbook.close()
} #end foreach
 
 $excel.quit()
 $excel = $null
 [gc]::collect()
 [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Answer (score -1):

Your solution is very easy. we don't need to use
some complex structures =) every xls file we can read in stream to find only one match to another *.xls
here is simple solution:

```
(gci d:\ -Filter "*.xls" -Recurse | Select-String -SimpleMatch ".xls").filename >> $HOME\matches.txt
```

if you are more or less familiar with powershell, you can easily make the edits you need